# PSK authentication in TinyDTLS

Tags: c, networking, cryptography, tls1.2, dtls

The PSK authentication with ciphersuite TLS_PSK_WITH_AES_128_CCM_8, carries PSK ID:

```
memcpy(p, handshake->keyx.psk.identity, handshake->keyx.psk.id_length);
p += handshake->keyx.psk.id_length;
```

So does this mean it serves as client authentication? If the server possesses the psk mapped to that psk_id it goes on with handshake, if not reports error.

Or is it server authentication by client which checks if server has the psk mapped to that psk_id, client can verify if the server is indeed in possession of psk mapped to the psk_id it sent, if and only if server sends a finished message, which client can authenticate correctly.

Answer (score 2):

> So does this mean it serves as client authentication? If the server
> possesses the psk mapped to that psk_id it goes on with handshake,

Yes, but this is not special for tinyDTLS, this is generally the way, how TLS_PSK_WITH_AES_128_CCM_8 [RFC4279 - PSK](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4279) works. Openssl would do it the same way.

> if not reports error.

Mostly not. Mostly this just means "the handshake timesout" without reporting an error / alert. In DTLS there are some security concerns around the alerts and their usage so it gets very common, not to send alerts.

> Or is it server authentication by client which checks if server has
> the psk mapped to that psk_id, client can verify if the server is
> indeed in possession of psk mapped to the psk_id it sent, if and only
> if server sends a finished message, which client can authenticate
> correctly.

The surprising answer is: both authenticates the other!
The data "name+secret" is somehow very similiar to username password. But in difference to a send password, the secret is never sent. Together which each peers random it is used to calculate the master secret and to calculate the client and servers FINISH message (both are different). Each peers checks the FINISH of the other, if it matches its own calculation, then the other share the same secret.

Comment: In RFC4279 says "The TLS handshake is authenticated using the Finished messages as usual."   So you say that its a mutual authentication, works both ways ???                                           Because I want to use TLS_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL (null encryption) and add a signature and hmac-key signed with it at CKE to authenticate client only. I dont care about encryption, just authentication and integrity.

Comment: > So you say that its a mutual authentication, works both ways ???. Using TLS_PSK_WITH_AES_128_CCM_8, yes. Using TLS_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL, I don't know.

Comment: Let me add: encryption to protect the visibility of message content is one part, protect the integrity of a message (from being altered) is the other part. Therefore a MAC for each message is used.